# Using mapM f [list] where f is defined with do notation

Tags: haskell

I currently have this code which will perform the `main'` function on each of the filenames in the list `files`.

Ideally I have been trying to combine `main` and `main'` but I haven't made much progress. Is there a better way to simplify this or will I need to keep them separate?

```
{- Start here -}
main :: IO [()]
main = do
    files <- getArgs
    mapM main' files

{- Main's helper function -}
main' :: FilePath -> IO ()
main' file = do 
    contents <- readFile file
    case (runParser parser 0 file $ lexer contents) of Left err -> print err
                                                       Right xs -> putStr xs
```

Thanks!

**Edit:** As most of you are suggesting; I was trying a lambda abstraction for this but wasn't getting it right. - Should've specified this above. With the examples I see this better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `forM`, which equals `flip mapM`, i.e. `mapM` with its arguments flipped, like this:

```
forM_ files $ \file -> do
  contents <- readFile file
  ...
```

Also notice that I used `forM_` instead of `forM`. This is more efficient when you are not interested in the result of the computation.

Comment: `forM_` and `mapM_` are also good because they make your intentions clearer, so you should generally always use them even if the performance doesn't matter.

Comment: Ah yes, I was attempting something similar to this but I am fairly new to `flip` and failed to think of using it here.

Answer (score 6):

The [`Control.Monad`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html) library defines the function [`forM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v%3aforM) which is `mapM` is reverse arguments. That makes it easier to use in your situation, i.e.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    files <- getArgs
    forM_ files $ \file -> do
        contents <- readFile file
        case (runParser f 0 file $ lexer contents) of
            Left err -> print err   
            Right xs -> putStr xs
```

The version with the underscore at the end of the name is used when you are not interested in the resulting list (like in this case), so `main` can simply have the type `IO ()`. (`mapM` has a similar variant called `mapM_`).

Comment: I'm using mapM_/forM_ now. :)